# Dynamic Table with Hide/Show features

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Here is my JSfiddle with the table environment: http://jsfiddle.net/pY66Q/

I am having trouble understanding how I can write my JavaScript in such a way that when the  element with the given class name of "pmap-program-name-label" is clicked, the click handler runs an expression that will only slideToggle the second child  of the  that contains the  that was clicked. I hope that makes sense.

My HTML:

```
<table class="pmap-font-clr-drk-grey">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Audit Program Results</th>
        <th>Open</th>
        <th>Closed</th>
        <th>Overdue</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="pmap-parent-row-odd">
        <td class="pmap-program-name-label"><div class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></div><span>2011 EH&amp;S Audits - USF Sites</span></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2011 EH&amp;S Audits - USF Sites</td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr class="pmap-parent-row-even">
        <td class="pmap-program-name-label"><div class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></div><span>2011 EH&amp;S Audits - USF Sites</span></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2011 EH&amp;S Audits - USF Sites</td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">1</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>

</tfoot>
```

My CSS:

```
table {
width: 100%;
border: 1px #eaeaea solid;
}

th {
width: 10%;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 4px #007290 solid;
padding: 5px 0;
}

th:first-child {
width: 60%;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 4px #007290 solid;
padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
font-family: 'Segoe UI Bold' sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
}

tr:nth-child(2) {
display: none;
}

td {
width: 10%;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 1px #eaeaea solid;
border-left: 1px #eaeaea solid;
padding: 0;
line-height: 30px;
}

td:first-child {
width: 60%;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px #eaeaea solid;
padding-left: 38px;
}

td.pmap-program-name-label {
width: 60%;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px #eaeaea solid;
padding: 2px 0 0 10px;
color: #007290;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
}

td.pmap-program-name-label span {
padding-left: 10px;
}

tr.pmap-parent-row-odd {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

tr.pmap-parent-row-even {
background-color: #F3F4F5;
}

td a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #007290;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

My JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/*
 ================================================
 Toggles Form Parent/Children Data Fields
 ================================================
 */

var sectionAnimating = false;

$('.pmap-program-name-label').click(function () {
    if (sectionAnimating == false) {
        $("tbody").find('tr:nth-child(2)').slideToggle(450, function () {
            sectionAnimating = false;
        });
        sectionAnimating = true;
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here u have code

```
(document).ready(function () {

    /*
     ================================================
     Toggles Form Parent/Children Data Fields
     ================================================
     */

    var sectionAnimating = false;

    $('.pmap-program-name-label').click(function () {
        if (sectionAnimating == false) {
            console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode)
            $(this.parentNode.parentNode).find('tr:nth-child(2)').slideToggle(450, function () {
                sectionAnimating = false;
            });
            sectionAnimating = true;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as I imagined it to and I learned about parentNode. I am currently reading eloquentjavascript.net (currently on chapter 3) as I am new to programming, but to say the least I am in love.

Comment: First of all read sth about javascript. Dom Node's are basic's of whole javascript ^^

Comment: "I am currently reading eloquentjavascript.net (currently on chapter 3)"